# How to Customize the Android Action Bar?

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, android-4.4-kitkat

My Android App's Action Bar doesn't display the icon defined in the  tag of the 'AndroidManifest.xml" nor am I able to change things such as colour of the action bar, or the colour of the title text on the action bar.

I am currently using minimum API 16 (Android Jellybean 4.1) and target SDK as the latest (at the time of writing) which is 22.

My styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">#006699</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="PACKAGE_NAME" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo_custom"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:logo="@drawable/logo_custom"
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Whenever I test the app on my phone (running 4.4.4 KitKat API 19) I just get the default black action bar with no application icon.

Does anyone know why this won't customize?

All help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Note: I am new to Android Development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your Styles.xml.

```
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"></style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/light_gray</item>
        <item name="background">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

**EDIT:**

You can change background of Actionbar programatically.

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.actionbar_background_color)));
```

You have to define your color code in color.xml like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="actionbar_background_color">#f4f2f2</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: Apart from the activity now having the light action bar due to the _light_ base theme, that hasn't fixed the problem, the color still doesn't change with the styles.xml.
Edit: Yes, I did change the AndroidManifest's theme to "@style/AppBaseTheme"

Comment: What do you want to change? background of Actionbar or actionbar's text color?

Comment: The background of the Action Bar - so instead of it being either black or white, make it grey/red to fit the rest of my app.

Comment: See edited answer to change background color programatically. define this code in you activity. use getSupportActionBar() if you are implement support library activity or getActionBar() for normal activity.

Comment: Defining the color in the activity class itself worked, I'm not sure why the xml method wasn't working but it's all good now I've done it programmatically. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) as it provide almost all customization which you want to do with action bar, 
You will find a working example [here](http://javatechig.com/android/android-lollipop-toolbar-example)

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="Theme.AndroidDevelopers" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@drawable/ad_selectable_background</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/MyDropDownListView</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyDropDownNav</item>
    <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorMultiple">@drawable/ad_btn_check_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorSingle">@drawable/ad_btn_radio_holo_light</item>
</style>
```

For More: [Android ActionBar](http://viralandroid.com/search/label/ActionBar)